# Showing a sequence in $\mathbb{N}$ is Cauchy

Tags: general-topology

For a metric $d(x,y) =\left| \frac{x}{1+|x|} - \frac{y}{1+|y|} \right|$

Where $d: \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$.

Prove that $\{ x_n \}$ in $\mathbb{R}$ given by $x_n = n$ is a Cauchy sequence with respect to $d$.

I am not sure of what would be a smart way to prove / disprove this. Here, since $n \in \mathbb{N}$, then we know that as the sequence continues the points $x_n$ and $x_m$ won't get closer than $1$, thus it is not Cauchy?

Comment: It isn't Cauchy in the *usual* metric on $\mathbb{R}$ but you have been given a different one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider $d(m,n)$:
$$
d(m,n)=\left|\frac{m}{1+m}-\frac{n}{1+n}\right|=
\left|\frac{m-n}{(1+m)(1+n)}\right|
$$
By the triangle inequality,
$$
d(m,n)\le \frac{m}{1+m}\frac{1}{1+n}+\frac{n}{1+n}\frac{1}{1+m}
\le\frac{1}{1+n}+\frac{1}{1+m}
$$
If $\varepsilon>0$, take an integer $N$ such that $N>2/\varepsilon$; if $m,n>N$ then
$$
d(m,n)\le\frac{1}{1+n}+\frac{1}{1+m}<
\frac{\varepsilon}{2}+\frac{\varepsilon}{2}=\varepsilon
$$

*Slow motion*

\begin{align}
d(m,n)
&=\left|\frac{m}{1+m}-\frac{n}{1+n}\right|
\\[6px]
&=\left|\frac{m-n}{(1+m)(1+n)}\right|
\\[6px]
&=\left|\frac{m}{(1+m)(1+n)}+\frac{-n}{(1+m)(1+n)}\right|
\\[6px]
&\le\left|\frac{m}{(1+m)(1+n)}\right|+\left|\frac{-n}{(1+m)(1+n)}\right|
&&\text{triangle inequality}
\\[6px]
&=\frac{m}{1+m}\frac{1}{1+n}+\frac{n}{1+n}\frac{1}{1+m}
\\[6px]
&\le\frac{1}{1+n}+\frac{1}{1+m}
&&\text{because }\frac{k}{1+k}\le1
\end{align}

Comment: I don't understand how you deduce that at the triangle inequality. Why do you multiply with $1/(1+n)$ and $1/(1+m)$ ? I don't understand :(

Comment: @Fredrik I added the steps

Comment: That is really great. Thanks for adding the middle steps. It is very clear to me now :)

Answer (score 1):

You have that $\frac{n}{1+n}=1-\frac1{1+n}<1$. Hence, for any $m>n$, we have: $$d(n,m)=|\frac{n}{1+n}-\frac{m}{1+m}|=|\frac1{1+m}-\frac1{1+n}|=\frac1{1+n}-\frac1{1+m}<\frac1{1+n}$$

Hence, for any $\epsilon>0$, choose $N$ such that $\frac1{N+1}<\epsilon$, then you have that $|x_n-x_m|<\epsilon$ for all $m,n>N$. Therefore, the sequence is Cauchy

Comment: It is a good observation at the beginning. Thanks for the response!

Answer (score 0):

You need to show that, for any small $\epsilon > 0$ given, there is some $N = N(\epsilon)$ such that for any $n, m > N$, you have $d(n,m) < \epsilon $ where $d$ is the distance that you have defined. This is simply the definition of the Cauchy sequence.

You need to do an explicit calculation with the metric to show that this is indeed the case.